# How can I getting start microcontroller programming?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

I have programming in high level language for several years, but recently I want do some adventage on hardware, I wish I can DIY some funny toys for my son.

At first, I thought embedded system is what I need, but I found it still too high level, and then I found microcontroller is more simple, but I don't know how to get start with it, and which chip should I choose, I wish I can choose a serial chip I can use it for most requirement but it is cheap( it is not a clear description, I know ).

Anything else should I know to get start with this?

### FYI: I wish it is absolutely low level

Comment: By "single chip" do you mean a "microcontroller"?  That is still and embedded system, I do not see the distinction.  You will still need to have your microcontroller mounted on a board with IO connectors.  Get yourself a suitable development kit for whatever device you choose.

Comment: You could start by visiting http://electronics.stackexchange.com and asking your question there; we're all about 'adventures in hardware'!

Comment: @Clifford I don't know what's the correct name. I means that the chip with very small RAM,flash inside

Comment: @Clifford thanks, I check wiki, I am sure what I want is just `Microcontroller`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start programming a microcontroller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78744/how-to-start-programming-a-microcontroller)

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, I believe what you are looking for is an [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) and [Sparkfun](http://www.sparkfun.com/) for parts / kits.  I'd start there, as you progress you can eventually move onto getting your own chip programmer instead of using a bootloader (like the Arduino has).  Maybe move to [microchip](http://www.microchip.com/) pic's or raw atmel chips... maybe even propeller.  As a starting point it doesn't get much easier than an arduino. Good luck, have fun.

Comment: I think Arduino is a lit bit high level.

Answer (score 3):

I will second on the arduino from sparkfun.  At the moment I get the lillypad (an arduino variation) or the arduino mini pro, both around $20, but the lilly pad has pins already on it for the serial/power to usb thing that you will also want to buy.

I am not a big fan of the avr instruction set, so I will throw in that you can also get the armmite pro, arduino footprint but arm based.  The mbed is relatively popular, super easy to use and you dont need anything else (the other two mentioned want for a serial to usb adapter for programming and power).

right now TI is pretty much giving away msp430 launchpad boards for $4.30 or $5 something at sparkfun, just through in a couple with the order.  the msp430 is a good instruction set, no harder or easier than anything else to program.  (they are all easy once you get the hang of it)

At the ti website there are the stellaris boards, loaded with gadgets like oled displays and things like that, it is trivial to brick the 811 board so I would recommend one of the others, the 1976 or whatever that number was wasnt a bad board, good price/feature for getting your feet wet.

All of the above have sandboxes to play in but you are not required or limited to the toolchains, programmers, host operating systems, etc.

I am not a pic fan from a product perspective, I cut my teeth as you are about to do, using a pic.  but moved away and never went back.  there are some boards at sparkfun for the pic.  I have not tried the propeller, I prefer chips I can program directly instead of an on-board interpreted basic or anything like that (I reprogram my arduinos and armmite pros as soon as I get them to wipe the interpreter and take over).

I think the arduino is probably the place to start to meet your description, there are many flavors now and partly because atmel does a very good job with documentation/support and perhaps for that reason there have been avr fanatics/lovers, and as a result of that there are TONS of hobby DIY projects that are arduino based.  With an arduino I think you will hit the ground running sooner than you would with another platform (even the ones I mentioned).

Comment: tomorrow is free day at sparkfun, last year despite upgrades their servers screeched to a halt.  so if you cannot get in dont think sparkfun is a bad place, it is I consider the best place in the US for these types of products, so wait until friday if you cannot get in on thursday.  ahh, sorry just saw that you are from China, sparkfun may not be your best resource, there are likely others closer to home.  olimex makes a number of good boards and are not pushing one chip over another, just provide hobby boards.

Comment: looking at sparkfun today, the reason I went with lilypad+ftdi usb thing is the lower cost of the lilypad and arduino pro mini.  but looking if you get the arduino uno which doesnt require the ftdi thing that is cheaper overall.  The reason I worry about the dollars is so you have the option of perhaps buying two things instead of one for the same money or if you short something out and melt something down you are out less money.  I usually buy two of everything expecting that I will blow one up, and or like it so much to turn one into a project and have another left to continue to play with.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you get a development starter-kit for an AVR device or a low end ARM Cortex-M3 (depending on your budget and performance requirements).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Clifford.

Also, take a look at TI's MSP430.  They are very simple to use and TI hosts a ton of sample projects with decent write-ups.

JMB